# Finding the max of a list with multiple elements

Tags: python, list, count, max

I am writing a Python program that produces a list similar to the code block below. The user inputs ten numbers, which are stored in a list. It counts the number of distinct objects. The first number in each ( ) is the number the user entered, and the second value is how many times it was entered. What I need to do is essentially print out to the user "The most common number is x which was entered y times".

```
organizedList = [(1.0, 5), (5.0, 3)]
print max(organizedList)
```

I tried a normal max command, but it chooses the second value as the max even thought it was chosen less often. Thank you for your help.

Comment: the max function will first look at the first number, returning the max from there. You could simply reverse the order in your array.

Comment: @quemeraisc that would work for this particular input, but is in no way general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers have already pointed out, you can tell the `max` function to only look at the second value by setting the `key` parameter. To output the result you can do this:

```
x,y = max(organizedList, key=lambda x: x[1])

print "The most common number is",x,"which was entered",y,"times."
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` option to `max`, which is a function that tells `max` what value to base the output on.

```
organizedList = [(1.0, 5), (5.0, 3)]
print max(organizedList, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This will use the 2nd element to determine the maximum value.

Comment: note: You need parenthesis to make this work in python 3: print (…)

Comment: @richard But since the OP was not using parenthesis, we can safely assume they were using Python 2.

Comment: Yes, the note if for Ron, in-case he comes here, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) has a key argument which you can use to specify on which tuple element the max should be found from.

```
>>> max(organizedList, key=lambda x: x[1])
(1.0, 5)
```

Alternatively if you aren't a fan of anonymous functions you could use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to use the second element similarly with

```
>>> max(organizedList, key=itemgetter(1))
(1.0, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normaly a list of tuples is sorted by the first element, but you can change  the way to get the max element by the key argument

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> organizedList = [(1.0, 5), (5.0, 3)]
>>> max(organizedList, key=itemgetter(1))
(1.0, 5)
```